# Converting ms since epoch timestamp to Date in Velocity templates

Tags: velocity

I have a date stamp, which should be a long, coming out of a database.

I know I need to turn it into a `Date`, then use a date formatter to output the right format, but I'm struggling with how (in Velocity template-ese) to turn a timestamp into a Date.

If this were java, I'd normally just do:  `Date d = new Date(msSinceEpoch)`.  What's the equivalent in Velocity?

Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
#set ( $date = $!n.myObj.getProperty('createdOn', 0) ))
#set ( $dateFormat = $dateTool.getDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s", $dateTool.getLocale(), $dateTool.getTimeZone()) )
#set ( $d2 = $dateFormat.parse($date) )
#set ( $display = $dateTool.format('medium', $d2) )
```

This approach throws an exception:

```
class java.text.SimpleDateFormat threw exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1429891200000"
```

Which I'm guessing is because the date is a string, not a `Long`.   Trying `$Long.parseLong($date)` seems to return null, and `MathUtil` doesn't get me anywhere because it has methods for converting to integer and double, but not long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found isn't pretty, but it works.  After investigating all of the various tools, I simply can't find anything in the template language or provided tools that can get the job done, but this approach works.

When initializing Velocity, I create a new object that adds the method I need:

```
public class AugmentedDateTool extends DateTool { 
    public Date epochToDate(String msSinceEpoch) { return new Date(Long.parseLong(msSinceEpoch)); }
}
```

(Note I'm riding on top of `DateTool` which is where it seems this functionality belongs, but is missing)

Then later, I add it to the context:

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("dateTool", new AugmentedDateTool());
```

Then, inside of the template, the solution becomes simple.   Given `$timestamp` which contains as a string, a long value (ms since the epoch), this happens:

```
#set ( $dateFormat = $dateTool.getDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s", $dateTool.getLocale(), $dateTool.getTimeZone()) )
#set ( $date = $dateTool.epochToDate($timestamp) )
#set ( $date = $dateTool.format('medium', $date))
```

This then results with `$date` having the right value.

Answer (score 2):

I just did this. The easiest way to do it so to put a new Date object in your context and then use the setTime method of that object and use your long as the parameter.

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContent();
context.put("date", new Date());
```

and then in your template

```
$date.setTime($unixTime)
Here is your date: ${date}
```

Comment: Why not do this before adding to the context?