# How to get a unix timestamp in VTL?

Tags: java, vtl

Is there any modify date format action (like `#set($a = $date.get('unix timestamp format code'))`) in **the velocity template language** which will allow to change date format to the form of **a unix timestamp** or can I get date in **a unix timestamp** format using variable like `$date` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31630813/3129992